# how to I echo out random lines from html file without the code?

Tags: php, html

I have to echo out random lines from a html file. My code works so far that I echo out a specific random number of lines, but the problem is that I echo out the html code and not the text that would appear on the html website. How to solve that problem?

```
My code:

foreach($files as $file) {

    if($file === '.' OR $file === '..' OR $file === 'thumbs.db' OR !is_dir($folder.'/'.$file)) {continue;}
    if(file_exists($folder.'/'.$file.'/doubleindemnity.gif') AND file_exists($folder.'/'.$file.'/DOUBLEINDEMNITY.htm')) {


        echo "<img src='$folder/$file/doubleindemnity.gif'>";
        $lines = file($folder.'/'.$file.'/DOUBLEINDEMNITY.htm');
        for($x = 1;$x<=15;$x++) {
        echo $lines[rand(0, count($lines)-1)]."<br>";
        }
        echo "</div>";

    }
 }
```

**At the moment I echo out something like this:**

mso-bidi-font-family:Courier;mso-ansi-language:DE'>
Cambria;mso-bidi-font-family:Cambria;mso-ansi-language:DE'>

mso-bidi-font-family:Courier;mso-ansi-language:DE'>

mso-bidi-font-family:Courier;mso-ansi-language:DE'>
DE'>

**What I want is something like this:**

A-1 LOS ANGELES - A DOWNTOWN INTERSECTION

```
           It is night, about two o'clock, very light traffic.

           At the left and in the immediate foreground a semaphore
           traffic signal stands at GO. Approaching it at about thirty
           miles per hour is a Dodge 1938 coupe. It is driven erratically
           and weaving a little, but not out of control.
```

Comment: Can you add the unwanted output to the post please?

Comment: If you `echo` all the time, the code is hard to read

Comment: Do a bulk echo for all the lines you're echoing next together with a " then you can echo variables at the same time without changing anything.

Comment: An example of the desired output would be helpful too.

Comment: I explained what I want above. How would I achieve that. I even tried to make a variable that says something like $Script=include($folder.'/'.$file.'/Romeo And Juliet Script.htm')

Answer (score 0):

Here: [strip_tags()](http://php.net/strip_tags)

Ex:

```
$str = strip_tags($input);
```

Comment: stript_tags didn't help. I have already tried that one by myself.

Comment: Could you provide me with the input? Based on the output you added it doesn't look like html, more like css.